# How to search for specific ID in SQLite android database and return its object

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to add a  method in myDBHandler that went passed an ID searches the row it belongs to and then make a new instance of a class and sets up all the information in the constructor like the name, the Id and the image.

So how do I get the row's position and populate my constructor with the columns?

Thanks!

Comment: row's position of what? you mean some Cursor? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: Check if the id exists in database, with this in hand, I would like to get the id's name and image. Like I want to select the row by the id that's passed in. Sorry if I sound confusing :/ Thanks

Comment: dont you have the position? where do you have id from? are we talking about `OnItemClickListener#onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` or similar?

Comment: What is the schema for your table?

Comment: I think I've figured it out, what do you think?

Comment: Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_GAMES + " where " + COLUMN_SEARCHID + "='" + id + "'" , null);

Comment: Yes, that will get a row where searchId matches the given id. Make sure you call `moveToFirst()` first--if that returns false, the cursor is empty.

Comment: where do you have id from?

Comment: thatks @Karakuri. The id is passed in the method as String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public MyObject getById(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String where = COLUMN_SEARCHID + " = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = {id};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_GAMES, null, where, whereArgs, null);
    MyObject obj = null;
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // read column data
            obj = new MyObject(...);
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: @JohnnyBoy well i think you dont need to query your db again, as you have the id taken from some Cursor so just use this Cursor to get your data